# g++ CreateProcess: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm trying to build Qt Creator from sources. Guys, I've checked posts on stackoverflow with reference to this error and I made sure that the `PATH` environmental variable is set for my compiler. I also followed instructions from the Qt `README`, yet I'm getting the following error:

```
g++ CreateProcess: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: please provide more information. Show the command line you are using.

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using? Can you run `g++ --version` from a command line prompt?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I'm using gcc 4.7. Before this comment I was trying to do it via qt for desktop mingw command prompt. Now I've tried to do it via Windows command prompt. It went through. The problem is that I'm getting another error which I'll create new Question for it.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `g++` compiler should be added to the **System variables** `PATH`, not the **User variables**.